# 行動規範の翻訳の方針を明示して下さい

Tags: 機能の要求, 翻訳

行動規範（[`/conduct` 以下の文章](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)）の英文は翻訳対象文字列として扱われており、システム的にはユーザーによる翻訳が可能な状態です。これらの文章をユーザーが翻訳あるいは翻訳の改善を行なうことは想定されていますか？

トップページはユーザーによる翻訳を避け、Stack Exchange社による翻訳がなされたと思わしき経緯が推測されます。しかし、今後の改善や他のページに関しての方針が不明です。Stack Exchange社の方針を明示いただくようお願いいたします。

ページの例:

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/abusive-behavior
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/disruptive-use
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/misleading-information
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/political-speech
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/self-harm
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/sensitive-content

Answer (score 1):

コミュニティのみなさまへ

このたび、Stack Overflow CM チームがこの質問を放置していないということを改めてお伝えするためにここに投稿させていただきました。現時点で共有できる具体的な情報はございませんが、行動規範及びポリシーの翻訳に関する社内議論が数ヶ月以内に再び本格的に開始できることを確認しました。答えが出るまでにはそこからさらに時間がかかりますが、進捗状況については随時お知らせいたします。

これがコミュニティが求めている答えではないかもしれないことを承知しておりますが、このトピックの進捗状況については常にコミュニティに情報を共有することをここに約束いたします。ご理解くださりありがとうございます。

I wanted to reach out and let the community know the Stack Overflow team has not forgotten about this question. While I do not have any immediate information I can share at this time, I can confirm that the internal discussions about this policy will kick off in earnest again in a couple of months. It will still take time after that to come to an answer, but I will keep you posted on the progress (with the assistance of Aki translating my drafts before I post them here - thank you!)

I know this may not be the answer the community wants right now, but I promise to keep the community informed on the progress of this topic.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information.